# How to formulate offeset function for every 6th column in different tabs?

Tags: excel

I've been struggling from last few days and this is my first post here.

Actually I am working on one excel report where in one tab of that report I have got the historical data of all the weekdays where all metrics are in column A and the heading has got the dates only (Starting from column B5 onwards). And I want to create all MONDAYS, TUESDAYS etc report from this historical report in the same workbook but in separate tabs .

So for: B5, C5, D5, E5, F5 (G5 column is used to separate the weeks)
        H5, I5, J5, K5, L5 (M5 column is again used to separate the week) and so on in History tab

I just need B5, H5, N5, T5 etc columns to create Monday report in tab name Mon
Similarly for Tue (C5, I5 etc), Wed (D5, J5 etc) as well.

Is there a formula that I can drag across all columns? Because basically I need every 6th column to create Mondays, Tuesdays etc reports. I tried offset, columns and indirect function but struggling a lot.

MANY THANKS,
GK

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way...

On your Monday sheet (the all data sheet is Sheet1):

- Column 'A' has formula: (e.g. in `A5`) `=Sheet1!A5` to copy the metric name
- Column 'B' and onwards has the formula (e.g. in `B5`) `=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A5,0,(COLUMN()-2)*6+1))`

What this is doing is using `OFFSET` to jump along columns... we calculate the column index using `(COLUMN()-2)*6+1` assuming Sheet1 starts on Monday. On the Tuesday sheet, it should end `+2` etc.

Comment: @user4201886 Did this work for you? Feel free to accept the answer!